Euler's formula for polyhedron
I'm curious about Euler's formula and how it applies to polyhedra. Specifically, I'm wondering if there are simple formulas or methods to figure out the number of vertices, faces, and edges for different shapes.
I've seen how binomial coefficients can help calculate edges, like with a cube, but I'm wondering if there are simpler, more general equations for other shapes, not just cube.

Euler most likely draw all the regular polyhedra, then counted the number of vertices, edges and faces of them all, then noticed something…

Any symmetry or regularity to your polyhedron might be used to shortcut counting in some way (e.g. mirror symmetry means you only have to count half the things and then double your result, making sure to take special care of the things that straddle the plane of symmetry). But most polyhedra aren't symmetric in any way. And for those that do have symmetry, there is still way too much variation in the kinds of symmetries you can have to give any kind of general giudance, at least that I'm aware of.

If all the vertices of your polyhedron "look the same" (ie you know how many triangles meet at each vertex, how many squares, etc), it's quite a nice exercise to work out the total number of faces, edges and vertices. (For example: if in a convex polyhedron, one triangle, two squares and a pentagon meet at each vertex, how many faces, edges and vertices does the polyhedron have?)

If you're looking for something more general, you need to say what information you have about the polyhedron.
